# What are the limitations of the Wikidata data model?

Tags: data-format, wikidata

Wikidata data model is [as follows](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Wikidata_datamodel#Table_structure_as_data_model):

[image]

The following diagram is a more summarized version of it ([source](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Introduction)):

[image]

All terms are defined [here](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Glossary).

I wonder what the limitations Wikidata data model are.

Comment: Wikidata's model is a superset of RDF, but I think RDF's limitations (if any) would be reflected in Wikidata.